# Neo4J Desktop Edition: Database failed to restart: DB [database-f6b0d9de-9954-4197-955c-ceb200b57d92] 'v3.4.7' exited with status 'KILLED'

Tags: neo4j

Friends,

I am getting the above error while restarting the neo4j graph database after terminating the session (exited out of Neo4J desktop browser due to long running query)

I am using Neo4J Desktop edition (Graph database created with version is 3.4.7) on Windows 10 machine

Here is what I was trying to do:

LOAD approx 500K records from a CSV file (filesize: 140MB). 
The command error-ed out after running for 15 min.

The `LOAD CSV` command is actually followed by a series of `MERGE` statements and one of the `MERGE` statement failed due to `null`(or blank value ) in one of the columns in CSV file.

However processed still created several thousands nodes and relations in the database.

Since the load error-ed out, I tried deleting all Nodes and Relations to avoid any unambiguous results by running below command: `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n`

The above command again was running forever possibly due to too many nodes and relations already created through the previous statement (just my guess!).

Since there is no way to kill the session from back-end in Neo4J Desktop edition, I closed the Neo4j Browser (assuming it will kill the current session) and then tried to restart the database, this is when I am now getting this error and the database is unable to restart now.

Need help on following:

1. Resolve the above Issue (unable to restart the database)
2. Any recommendation on setting the configuration parameters (viz heapsize, pagecache etc.) in order to improve the performance of high volume data load (approx. 500K - 1 million records) CSV file in Neo4j. I have a Windows 10 (64-Bit) machine with 8GB RAM
3. Is Neo4j Graph database ver 3.4.7 stable or should we use 3.4.1 instead ?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

After an automatic update of the apoc plugin today, I encountered the same error message at the next restart of the Neo4j 3.4.7 database. In file debug.log I found a bunch of corresponding warn messages (`"Failed to load 'apoc.util.s3.S3URLConnection'"`, etc. ).

Workaround: When I removed or uninstalled the new apoc-3.4.0.3.jar from the plugin directory and left the old apoc-3.4.0.2.jar untouched in the same directory, I was able to start the database at least.

Comment: I ended up dropping the database and recreated a new one. However your inputs are valuable and will keep in mind for future...Thank you!